# Which article to use before a noun that is being repeated in a sentence?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Should I use a definite or indefinite article before a noun that is being repeated in a sentence?

For example, should I use "the" or "a" in the following sentence before the second word "attempt"?

> She is always attuned to the rigorous perception and memorization of
> the information being taught, while not subjecting it to any attempt of
> critical analysis, much less **the** attempt of discussing it.

Or should I just refrain from using any article there?

Comment: *...while not subjecting it to any attempt **at** critical analysis, much less **any / an** attempt **to discuss** it.*

Comment: Question for the close-voters: *Please edit your question to focus on something in particular that you are unsure about* - how much more specific can this question get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Much less attempt of discussing it] is the correct form

You don't need to use (the) after attempt, because we have already knew what kind of attempt it is talking about.

Also, We don't usually use (the) after much less.

Comment: When negating the specific word "attempt", it's common to use "any", as already found earlier in the paragraph.  (I'd also suggest changing "attempt of ...ing" to "attempt to ...".)

Thus: "...not subjecting it to any attempt of critical analysis, much less any attempt to discuss it."

Comment: @tea-and-cake - Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  Sorry, I should also have said: "attempt of" is never really idiomatic, it should be "attempt to" + verb, or "attempt at" + noun.  So my final suggestion would be: "...not subjecting it to any attempt *at* critical analysis, much less any attempt *to* discuss it."  (Or alternatively, "...much less any attempt *at* discuss*ing* it".)

Comment: There is much wrong with this answer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - What exactly?